# Need help scanning through lines lines of a .csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, csv

I need to scan each line in my .csv file but once I get to the end it gives me an error.

```
def percentage():
    for line in csv_file:
        temp = line.strip("\n")

        measureType = temp.split(",")[5][1: -1]

        if measureType == "PERCENT":
            year = line.split(",")[1][1: -1]
            percentage = line.split(",")[6][1: -2]
            country = line.split(",")[0][1: -1]

            if float(percentage) < 50:
                output.addCountry(country, year, percentage)
```

As I scan through the file, once it gets to the end, it gives me an error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

for the line below:

```
measureType = temp.split(",")[5][1: -1]
```

I am extremely confused and don't know what I have to fix.

Comment: What is the last line in your file?

Comment: It sounds like this file has an empty line at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Going off of what cosinepenguin said, you will have to look at the very last line.

The reason for getting the error is because you are trying to divide the line by each comma and then trying to get an index that doesn't exist.

Example:

```
array = [0, 1, 2]
```

In this array there are 3 indexes, so if you try to get and index higher than the last one, you will get the error `IndexError: list index out of range`.

---

So make sure that the last line, after being split up, has all the indexes you need.